# Input toggle focus hiding submit button when trying to click it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form that if you click on the input field giving it focus the submit button displays.

However the issue I'm having is that when you try to click on the submit button it disappears as the focus has been removed from the input.

Here is my code:

```
<form  method="post" id="subForm" class="clearfix">
    <input id="fieldEmail" placeholder="email address" type="email"/>
    <button type="submit"><i class="arrow"></i></button>
</form>


$('#fieldEmail').focus(function () {
    $(this).next().addClass('visible');
}).blur(function () {
    $(this).next().removeClass('visible');
});
```

[And here is a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cnLon9k3/)

What is the best way to keep the toggling of class 'visible' but allow me to click the submit button?

Comment: your updated and working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cnLon9k3/2/

Comment: why do you want to click it if it's not visible ?

Comment: @Mritunjay I want to be able to click it only when it is visible.

Comment: @InsaneSkulll thank you for the fiddle.  However when I click on the white of the page the submit button is still there. I need it to hide once the focus has gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to do with the order of events.

You can use `mousedown` to detect *where* the focus moves to because it triggers before the `blur`:

```
(function () {
    var submit_focus = false;
    $('#fieldEmail').focus(function () {
        $(this).next().addClass('visible');
    }).blur(function () {
        if (submit_focus) {
            submit_focus = true;
        } else {
            $(this).next().removeClass('visible');
        }
    });

    $('#submit').mousedown(function () {
        submit_focus = true;
    });
}());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cnLon9k3/4/

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to put a check inside the function which hides the button and see if the input field has some value (if yes, you wouldn´t want to hide the button, or?)

e.g:

```
$('#fieldEmail').focus(function () {
    $(this).next().addClass('visible');
}).blur(function () {
    if($(this).val() === ""){
        $(this).next().removeClass('visible');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

We can have a check that **on blur** of textfield, the **new focused** element is **button or not**.

```js
$('#fieldEmail').focus(function () {
    $(this).next().addClass('visible');
}).blur(function () {
  if(!event.relatedTarget||event.relatedTarget.type!='submit')
    $(this).next().removeClass('visible');
});
```

```css
form {
  color:#333;
  position: relative;
}

input {
  padding:0 5px 5px;
  text-align: center;
  border:none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size:12px;
  width:170px;
  margin-left:15px;
  float:left;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

button {
  display: none;

  background: #ff0000;
  border:none;

}


.arrow {
  background:#ff0000;
  width:15px;
  height:15px;
  display: block;
 
}

.visible {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form  method="post" id="subForm" class="clearfix">
    <input id="fieldEmail" placeholder="email address" type="email"/>
    <button type="submit"><i class="arrow"></i></button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to capture each `click` event on `document` and if the `target` of that `event` is not **submit button** or **email input** then hide the `submit button` as below and remove the **blur event** from `input`

```
$(document).on('click',function(e){
    if(e.target.type!="submit" && e.target.type !="email")
    {
        $('#fieldEmail').next().removeClass('visible')
    }
});
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/cnLon9k3/5/)**